# Replace the user selected file from <input type="file"> with a client-side generated file

Tags: javascript, fileapi, file-io

Here is my problem.
I have a file upload form:

```
<form>
  <input type="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When the file is selected (its an image in my case) - I resize it using FileAPI and canvas.
The bit that I can't figure out is - how would I replace the selected file with mine, so when the user clicks 'Submit' - it will upload the modified file instead of the original one?

All the solutions I have looked at so far suggest to upload the file via AJAX, but it doesn't suit my case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to convert the image into a File and just assign it to the <input> like this: input.files[0] = File;